# Node.js - Create a proxy, why is request.pipe needed?

Tags: node.js

Can some one explain this code to create a proxy server.  Everything makes sense except the last block.  request.pipe(proxy  - I don't get that because when proxy is declared it makes a request and pipes its response to the clients response.  What am I missing here?  Why would we need to pipe the original request to the proxy because the http.request method already makes the request contained in the options var.

```
var http = require('http');

function onRequest(request, response) {
    console.log('serve: ' + request.url);

    var options = {
        hostname: 'www.google.com',
        port: 80,
        path: request.url,
        method: 'GET'
    };

    var proxy = http.request(options, function (res) {
        res.pipe(response, {
            end: true
        });
    });

    request.pipe(proxy, {
        end: true
    });
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What am I missing here? [...] the http.request method already makes the request contained in the options var.

---

[`http.request()`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) doesn't actually send the request in its entirety immediately:

> [...] With `http.request()` one must always call `req.end()` to signify that you're done with the request - even if there is no data being written to the request body.

The [`http.ClientRequest`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest) it creates is left open so that body content, such as JSON data, can be written and sent to the responding server:

```
var req = http.request(options);

req.write(JSON.stringify({
    // ...
}));

req.end();
```

`.pipe()` is just one option for this, when you have a readable stream, as it will [`.end()` the client request by default](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options).

---

Although, since `GET` requests rarely have a body that would need to be piped or written, you can typically use [`http.get()`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback) instead, which calls `.end()` itself:

> Since most requests are GET requests without bodies, Node provides this convenience method. The only difference between this method and `http.request()` is that it sets the method to GET and calls `req.end()` automatically.

```
http.get(options, function (res) {
    res.pipe(response, {
        end: true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: the event loop.  I don't want to talk too far out of my ass, and this is where node.js gets both beautiful and complicated, but the request isn't strictly MADE on the line declaring proxy: it's added to the event loop. So when you connect the pipe, everything works as it should, piping from the incoming request > proxy > outgoing response.  It's the magic / confusion of asynchronous code!